# Suppose $x_{\theta} = (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta )) \in \mathbb R^2$. Prove $||x_{\theta + \theta^{'}} - x_{\theta}|| = ||x_{\theta^{'}} - x_{0}||$.

Tags: calculus, geometry

> Suppose $x_{\theta} = (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta )) \in \mathbb R^2$.
>
> Prove $||x_{\theta + \theta^{'}} - x_{\theta}|| = ||x_{\theta^{'}} - x_{0}||$.

How do I prove that these values are equal corresponding to the distance between two pairs of points, with common angle, lying on the unit circle.

**I want to prove that these numbers are equal: $||x_{\theta + \theta^{'}} - x_{\theta}||, ||x_{\theta^{'}} - x_{0}||$, so please don't give a geometric proof saying that similar triangles has the same side length.**

This identity is used in a book to prove the identity $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$ and later the similar identity for $\sin(a+b)$, so please don't use these in an answer.

[image]

Comment: Your statement is equivalent to the fact that a rotation with angle $\theta$ preserves angles.

Comment: Don't you mean: a rotation with an angle $\theta$ preserve the norm (length) of the vector ?
(If so, the book is using this fact before the section of orthogonal matrices) - I assume, since they state this, it must be prove able by calculus or something.

Comment: You look rather undecided : first you say "please don’t use trigonometrical identities" then "it must be provable by calculus or something. "

Comment: I refer only to two identities not all.

Comment: Those two identities you mentioned are the two basic ones. All the others follow from them. I believe you’re too confused at the moment about what you really want, to accept any answer.

Comment: Please see the picture I've added. Here we use the equal distances to prove the trignometric identities, so in proving these equal distances we can't use the identities.

Comment: I don't see any calculus anywhere on this page. As far as I can tell, they're using the fact that rotations preserve length as a background fact. Why don't you like the geometric proof?

Comment: Because the proof depends on the values of the norms are equal. Thus we must show these numbers are the same, that is the norm indeed compute the same value for both vectors.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: Any proof that does not use geometry must use in some way the properties $\cos$ and $\sin$ for sums/differences, and that is not permitted. If you want to use calculus, you use derivatives, and the proof that $\sin'=\cos$ and $\cos'=-\sin$ uses the identies you want to prove. To prove that the two norms are equal is the same thing as to prove two segments have equal lengths, which is a good and simple geometry problem.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen Yes the only non-circular solution to this problem is to use basic geometry. Anything else ultimately relies on the identities in question.

Comment: But using geometry makes it hard to prove that the norm reflect what you prove using a geometric argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a try. Let $x : [0,2\pi] \to \Bbb{R}^2$ be the arclength parametrization of the unit circle with $x(0)=(0,1)$ turning counterclockwise. You can probably prove that $x(\theta)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ (but I will NOT use this equality in the following).

Then if $f(\theta)= \|x(\theta+\tau)-x(\theta)\|$ with $\tau$ fixed, we have
$$ f'(\theta) = \frac{\langle x(\theta+\tau)-x(\theta),x'(\theta+\tau)-x'(\theta)\rangle}{\|x(\theta+\tau)-x(\theta)\|}=0$$
where $\langle\rangle$ is the usual scalar product. The above equality holds because

- we have the equality $1=\|x(\theta\|$ which by differentiation gives us $\langle x'(\theta),x(\theta)\rangle=0$
- $\theta \mapsto \langle x(\theta+\tau),x(\theta)\rangle$ is constant as the scalar product of two vectors with constant angle $\tau$ between them. Differentiating we get
  $$ \langle x(\theta+\tau),x'(\theta)\rangle+ \langle x'(\theta+\tau),x(\theta)\rangle =0$$
  (this is again geometry)

Therefore $f$ is constant and $f(\theta)=f(0)$ which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks @BeniBogosel. I didn't knew the prove of these derivatives ($\cos,\sin$) relied on these identities. Is your proof valid then ? Are we using what we are trying to prove ? 

In essence, we must prove the Euclidean norm maps these "rotated" points on the unit circle to the same value using just the definition ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: I don't think we need anything related to sin and cos (apart of their definitions) for the above proof to work. I still like the geometric argument better.

Comment: Thank you. Would you prove $$x(\theta)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$$ by integration or ? What is the geometric argument specifically ?

Comment: If you start at $x(0)$ and go to $x(\theta)$ on the circle, you go on a path of length $\theta$ (as a consequence of the arclength parametrization). The definition of the angles in radians tells you that an arc of length $\theta$ on the unit radius circle corresponds to an arc of angle $\theta$ (at the center of the circle). Therefore $x(\theta)$ makes an angle of $\theta$ with $x(0)$ and using right triangles you can prove that $x(\theta)=(\cos\theta,\sin \theta)$.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. And what about your geometric argument that you like better ? Can you say a few words about it ?

Comment: where have you found the definitions for the derivative of your functions ? This is not the usual derivative as I know it ?

Comment: For the geometric argument, look here: http://gradestack.com/CBSE-Class-9/Theorem-1-Equal-chords-of-a-Circl/14904-2953-4023-study-wtw The idea is that equal chords oppose equal angles at the center and conversely. Your norm equality says exactly that. There is also a rotation argument mentioned in the comments to the question. As for the derivative, if $x,y$ are vector functions of $\theta$ then the derivative of $\langle x(\theta),y(\theta)\rangle$ is taken just like the derivative of a product. (it is mentioned as property 7 in this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)

Comment: Thank you. I think I finally fully understand your proof. You conclude that $f$ is constant because if $f^{'} = 0$ then $f = c$ right ? and we consider $x(\theta)$ as a vector function of real valued functions $\sin, \cos$ and the inner product (scalar) is equal to a sum of products of these $\sin, \cos$ ?

Comment: I do not use the fact that $x(\theta)=(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$, because then my reasoning is circular. I use just the fact that $x(\theta)=(x_1(\theta),x_2(\theta))$ and the usual formula for the scalar product.

Comment: But how do you justify that the derivative of $x(\theta)$ actually exists ? As I see it, you just take the derivative assuming the derivative exist for $x(\theta)$ ?

Comment: The circle is a smooth surface (write any analitic representation) therefore its parametric representation is smooth.

Comment: Is that a rigorous argument? If so I can accept the proof.

Comment: Yes, it is as rigorous as it gets. The circle is smooth, which means that it is locally the graph of a smooth function like $y=g(x)$, so locally you could write $x(t)=(t,g(t))$ in a certain coordinate system (possibly rotated), which is smooth. Reparametrizing to arclength preserves smoothness.

Comment: But proving the derivatives of $\sin$ and $\cos$ relies on using the addition identities like $\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\sin b\cos a$ which are trying to be established.

Comment: I did not use the derivatives of sin and cos above.

Comment: How do one show that the derivative always exist for a function with a smooth graph ? and what is smooth to be specific ?

Comment: Smooth means of class $C^\infty$ which is differentiable by definition. In the case of the circle you have $x \to \sqrt{1-x^2}$ on an interval $(-1,1)$.